# don't have "sufficient right" to my own TFS 2010

Tags: permissions, team-foundation-server, accounts

after I removed an active directory domain service, I lost all my accounts...then not only the SQL server and the TFS stopped working, the TFs administration console also says that I don't have sufficient right to add members... 
Now I manage to get the SQL server kind of running, and I can see my project in team explorer, but the TFS still says SQL access denied, SQL server says I don't have permission to add new logins or add my admin account to sysadmin, the TFS still give me the TF246017 tfs could not connect to the database and I don't have sufficient right to add member to any of the project groups...

Anybody knows how can I get all these permissions back....?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the repair for TFS 2010 in add or remove programs control panel. Make sure you are logged in wtih an account that has admin rights for the local machine. Good luck.